# Reloading HighCharts data using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I'm trying to replace the highcharts that I loaded using ajax. Apparently what I am doing is that I would get new values from the user, send the new values thru Ajax, then return an entirely new graph(different graph type with different data) so what I'm doing is this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: $("#searchForm").attr( 'action' ),
         data: $("#searchForm").serialize(),
        success: function(response) {   
                    $('#container').highcharts({ response  });
           }
    });
```

But what happens is that it just loads a blank graph.

this is my highcharts code:

```
    chart: { type: 'bubble', zoomType: 'xy'}, title: { text: 'Day at a Glance' }, tooltip: {}, xAxis:
 {categories:[ 'Delta Air Lines' ]}, yAxis: { title: { text: '# of Crew' } }, series: [{name: '# of 
Passengers', URLs:[ '#'], data: [['1',1,0]], point: { events: {click: function() { var someURL = 
this.series.userOptions.URLs[this.x]; if (someURL) window.open('http://'+someURL); }}} }]
```

Is there something wrong with the way I call my ajax or there is something wrong with my highcharts code?

Comment: Can you put your code somehow neater? Or maybe show it in `JSfiddle`?

Answer (score 0):

In the response you need to get json, like

```
{
    chart:{
    //any options
    },
    series: [{
    data:[1,2,3] //any points
    }]
}
```

So you cannot use something like `highcharts({ response  })` but `highcharts(response)`